# jQuery DOM Traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I've been trying to bind a `$.click` handler to a sibling element, but can't seem to find a way to properly select the element to animate. Here is the basic structure of the DOM tree that I'm working with:

```
<section id="a">
    <div id="b" class="foo" draggable="true">
        <header style="cursor:pointer;">1.</header>
        <p class="foo">Bar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="c" class="foo" draggable="true">
        <header style="cursor:pointer;">2.</header>
        <p class="foo">Bar</p>
    </div>
    <!-- and so on... -->
</section>
```

Now, when a user clicks a `<header>`, I would like the sibling `<p>` to perform a `jQuery.slideToggle()`. At this point, I have the following JavaScript, but to no avail:

```
$('header').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children("p").slideToggle('slow');
    // I also tried:
    $(this).parent().children("p.foo").slideToggle('slow');
    // but as I expected, there was no difference.
});
```

So to clarify, a very drawn-out version of this would be:

```
$('div#b.foo header').click(function(){
    $('div#b.foo p.foo').slideToggle('slow');
});
$('div#c.foo header').click(function(){
    $('div#c.foo p.foo').slideToggle('slow');
});
// ...
```

Please ask me to elaborate if this is not clear enough.

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/KZyKU/1/). You need to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$('header').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/KZyKU/2/)

[`.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by initializing the click handler on document ready. The solution is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('header').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```